How to make tikzpicture span several pages
I need to create a long vertical flowchart diagram, which should span several pages. I decided to create it in latex and asked ChatGPT how to accomplish this. He answered like this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
    \node (a) [process, below=of start] {A};
    \node (b) [process, below=of a] {B};
    \node (c) [process, below=of b] {C};
    \node (d) [process, below=of c] {D};
    \node (e) [process, below=of d] {E};
    \node (f) [process, below=of e] {F};
    \node (g) [process, below=of f] {G};
    \node (h) [process, below=of g] {H};
    \node (i) [process, below=of h] {I};
    \node (j) [process, below=of i] {J};
    \node (k) [process, below=of j] {K};
    \node (end) [startstop, below=of k] {End};
    
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (a);
    \draw [arrow] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I changed node contents to simplify example and specified only two arrows for simplicity and brevity.
The problem with it, that the library draws only on single page. When diagram takes more space than available, the program moves it on next page and protrude into bottom margin.

What is ChatGPTs answer to your question? Why do you need us?

@MS-SPO Doesn't last sentence state it? ChatGPT answer is code in body.

Simple answer: Not possible, a tikzpicture forms a box that's not breakable.

@Skillmon Thank you! Could you tell, please, how to implement my requirement with several tikzpicture?

How are your readers supposed to read and understand that? What are your requirements? You just dumped a pile of GPT-code on us, but your question doesn't explain anything.

wow, that code is really outdated. Asking chatgpt seems not such a good idea...

Do I need to explain my sarcasm? // However, if you look at how huge projects handle this, like in project management, architecture, system design, the key is „modular black box design“: simple and concise on top level, more detailed in the zoomed-in BB. Which translates into: divide your big chart into a few smaller chunks, easier to understand and reveal its „big picture“ (in contrast to an intermingled set of lines, boxes etc.)

Did you forget about https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon ? You have to break it yourself. Using this situation for good puts you on the module-track https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730556/how-to-make-tikzpicture-span-several-pages#comment1819306_730556 .
